# MQL5 readfile while being write by another program

Tags: python, file, read-write, mql5

I got a program that using 2 different language, MQL5 and Python. As a bridge between 2 script, I'm using 2 text file. MQL5 will write a file. Python will standby and periodically check if said file exist. If it indeed exist, Python will read the file then write another file, before deleting file that have been read. MQL5 after writing the file will go to standby and periodically check if Python have produced a reply. If reply filename exist, it will read said file.

Unfortunately, MQL5 keep trying to read the reply file while it being written by Python. It cause MQL5 to throw error and if I force it to read it, it will read blank file. Is there anyway to avoid this? Is there anyway to detect if a file have finish being modify by another program in MQL5?

Below is the code I used to try to handle this problem to no avail.

```
while(!FileIsExist("output.txt"))
           {

           }

         if(FileIsExist("output.txt"))
           {
            ResetLastError();
            do
              {
               int file_handle=FileOpen("output.txt", FILE_READ|FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_TXT);
              }
            while(file_handle==5004);
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove `FILE_SHARE_READ` from the flags. For a shared read, it will try to read something when other applications have access to it (e.g. write). Without that, MQL5 will receive an error (and probably sleep for a while?) until Python script closes that file and unblocks it.

Comment: @DanielKniaz just tried that, same result

Comment: ok, what is `while(file_handle==5004)` ? The handle is likely to be a smaller number, starting from 1 or 10, 5004 is probably your error. So Sleep `while(_LastError==5004)` or until `file_handle!=INVALID_HANDLE`